# paired data for a facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Imagine I have data `foo` below. Each row contains a measurement (`y`) on a `species` and each `species` is paired with another (`species.pair`). So in the example below, species `a` is paired with `e`, `b` with `f`, and so on. The number of observations for each species varies. I'd like to plot the density of each species's distribution along with its partner's distribution in its own facet. Below I hand coded this with the column `sppPairs`. The `species` are all unique and each has a match in `species.pair`. I'm unsure of how to make the grouping column `sppPairs` below. I'm sure there is some clever way to do this with `{dplyr}` but I can't figure out what to do. Some kind of pasting `species` to `species.pair` I imagine? Any help much appreciated.

```
foo <- data.frame(species = rep(letters[1:8],each=10),
                  species.pair = rep(letters[c(5:8,1:4)],each=10),
                  y=rnorm(80))
# species and species pair match exactly
all(unique(foo$species) %in% unique(foo$species.pair))

# what I want
foo$sppPairs <- c(rep("a:e",10),
                  rep("b:f",10),
                  rep("c:g",10),
                  rep("d:h",10),
                  rep("a:e",10),
                  rep("b:f",10),
                  rep("c:g",10),
                  rep("d:h",10))

p1 <- ggplot(foo,aes(y,fill=species))
p1 <- p1 + geom_density(alpha=0.5)
p1 <- p1 + facet_wrap(~sppPairs)
p1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `apply` on the appropriate columns to `paste` the sorted elements together in the correct order (otherwise a:e is different from e:a and so on, and you end up with 8 groups instead of 4):

```r
library(ggplot2)

foo <- data.frame(species = rep(letters[1:8], each = 10),
                  species.pair = rep(letters[c(5:8, 1:4)], each = 10),
                  y = rnorm(80))

foo$sppPairs <- apply(foo[c("species", "species.pair")], 1, 
                      function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ":"))

ggplot(foo, aes(y, fill = species)) +
 geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
 facet_wrap(~sppPairs)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.